# Does useBean id create an instance of the bean class that it is refering to?

Tags: java, jsp

**This is a main.JSP jsp**

```
<html>
<body>``
      <center>
         *<h2>Using JavaBeans in JSP</h2>
         <jsp:useBean id = "test" class = "servletexample1.TestBean" />*
         <jsp:setProperty name = "test"  property = "message" 
            value = "Hello JSP..." />

         <p>Got message....</p>
         <jsp:getProperty name = "test" property = "message" />
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

**This is a TestBean Class**

```
package servletexample1;

/* File: TestBean.java */
   public class TestBean {
       private String message = "No message specified";

       public String getMessage() {
          return(message);
       }
       public void setMessage(String message) {
          this.message = message;
       }
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          TestBean test = new TestBean(); 
      }
    }
```

what exactly is *test* in main.jsp? Is it the instance of the TestBean() class?what exactly does this statement `<jsp:useBean id = "test"` do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `useBean` does create an instance. Mind that jsp functions are just syntax sugar to regular java. Everything still works as it would in regular java; you just use a different syntax.

Also, `id` is used to identity that bean within its scope. Example:

```
<jsp:useBean id="foo" class="fooClass" />

<%
    foo.PrintSomething()
%>
```

So yes, `foo` is an instance of `fooClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you declare a bean id in `useBean` tag it is the instance of that class like just you create a instance core java.
In your code `test` is the instance of `TestBean` class.